# Create new point feature of a shapefile if a condition is met when creating a new line feature

Tags: pyqgis, shapefile

I am working with multiple ESRI Shapefiles, both Line and Point types. Every shapefile has a set of fields and some of them share common values (by default) or have values that refer to each other from a logical point of view. I need the shapefiles to be like they are so I cannot alter or join fields on them to achieve the result.

Basically, I am trying to find a way to create a *New Point Feature* of the shapefile `STOCK`, compiling all its fields in the process (ID, CABLE, LENGTH, CITY, COORDINATES), if a condition is met when creating a *New Line Feature* in the shapefile `CABLES`.

The exact example of pseudo-code is

```
IF(CABLE.LENGTH > 100, STOCK.CREATE_POINT(ID, CABLE.ID, 10, X.CITY, CABLE.COORDINATES))
```

Where CABLE.COORDINATES is exactly the coordinate of the last node of the line geometry. I need it to be this so that when I finish creating a line and it is longer than 100, a new point feature with its label and symbol already set in the STOCK shapefile appears at the end of the line and I can then move it to the appropriate final position.

I am using QGIS 10.10 for compatibility reasons of the base-project. I am trying to upgrade it with new automated features to make the job faster but I am new to gis. I will then apply more complicated boundaries based on multiple fields to get the exact STOCK Length I need.

Comment: If it's possible to move away from shapefiles (highly recommend in general, for many good reasons), this is what a "database trigger" is for. It could even be made to do things like deleting the point if the length goes back below your threshold.

Comment: Unfortunately, shapefiles are required because are the standard date format for the whole project. They are still used for compatibility reasons with very old systems